# printing dict keys 'value' times and alternatively like round robin scheduling

Tags: loops, python-2.7, dictionary

```
obj = {'a1':3,'a2':5,'a3':1}
```

I know how to iterate over it:

```
for k,v in obj.iteritems():
    print k
```

output:

```
a1 a2 a3
```

For printing keys `value` times, I did:

```
for k,v in obj.iteritems():
    for v in range(0,v):
        print k
```

Output i get:

```
a1 a1 a1 a2 a2 a2 a2 a2 a3
```

But I want to have output based on `value` times and then alternating:

Desired output:

```
a1 a2 a3 a1 a2 a1 a2 a2 a2
```

Comment: Do you want the keys in sorted order? The fact that you are getting them so in your current code is a coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recipe using itertools. You'll need to use the `roundrobin` recipe from the itertools page [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) also duplicated below:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle, repeat

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))


# Now, the real recipe starts
obj = {'a1':3,'a2':5,'a3':1}
objiter = [repeat(x,y) for x,y in obj.items()]
objlist = list(roundrobin(*objiter))
objlist
['a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2']
```

Note this didn't give you exactly what you are looking for... as one of the other answers said, you can use a sorted version of the dictionary (which is also included below), or you could use an OrderedDict in the first place. Remember if you use an OrderedDict and initialize it like `my_odict = OrderedDict({1:1, 2:2, 3:3})`, that python will *first* create the dictionary - unordered - and then create the OrderedDict from it, which is probably not what you intended.

Sorted:

```
objiter = [repeat(x, obj[x]) for x in sorted(obj.keys())]
objlist = list(roundrobin(*objiter))
objlist
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2']
```

Obviously, the ordered dictionary recipe is the same as the regular dictionary recipe, just pass in an ordered dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a neat way to do this. You could take this approach, which makes a copy of `obj` then uses the values in the copy to keep track of how many times to `print` each key:

```
out = obj.copy()
while sum(out.values()):
    for k in sorted(out):
        if out[k]:
            print k
            out[k] -= 1
```

Comment: True, and it would be more efficient to move `sorted` outside the loop if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner: (assumes `None not in obj`)

```
[x for y in map(None, *[[k]*v for k, v in sorted(obj.iteritems())]) for x in y if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using no extra space (`sorted` may use extra O(n) space), python 3:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest, repeat
obj = {'a1':3,'a2':5,'a3':1}
[x for x in chain(*zip_longest(*(repeat(k, v) for k,v in sorted(obj.items())))) if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(0, max(obj.values())):
    for k,v in obj.iteritems():
        if v > i:
           print k
```

Comment: returns- a3 a3 a1 a3. Also a closing brace is missing in first line